# Unable to create a directory or file for my app even though the permissions are there

Tags: java, android

I have an App that I made years ago. Recently I just recompiled it with a very few changes just so that I could change the target SDK and still be listed in the play store.

As it turns out this fundamentally broke the app in certain phones including my own.I tested it on another phone before I uploaded it and it worked fine (Android Version 8.1.0). My phone has Android 11 (where it doesn't work).

The problem seems to be in the ability to create and read files in the internal storage and whole point of the app is to maintain a single file.

Here is a function that I made that attemps to create a directory. This is just a test function that I call on creation, it wasn't part of the original app:

```
 public static void AttemptDirCreate(){
    String dirname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/this_is_a_test";
    File dir = new File(dirname);

    System.err.println("Attempting to create directory: '" + dirname + "'");

    boolean make_result = false;
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        try {
            make_result = dir.mkdir();
        }
        catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.err.println("ERROR. Could not make dir. Reason: " + se.getMessage());
        }
    }

    if (make_result){
        System.err.println("MKDir result is true");
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("MKDir result is false");
    }

    if (dir.exists()){
        System.err.println("Dir has been created");
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Was unable to create dir");
    }

}
```

The problem is that directory is not created and NO exception is thrown. When I go into app info I see the permissions for Files and Media.

The path where the directory is being tried to be created is: '/storage/emulated/0/this_is_a_test'

Which as far as I cant tell is the correct path. The app did ask me for permissions when first installed.

So why can't it create the directory? How can I find out the issue and fix it?

Just to clarify, this exact same function WORKS on Android 8.1.0, but it does nto work on Android 11. Not sure, what the cutoff point is.

Comment: Better: `if(!dir.mkdir()) return;` Display a toast too to inform the user. And mkdirs() does not throw. It returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create files and directories in root of external storage for Android 11+ devices.

Instead use one of the public directories that are already there.

Like DCIM, Pictures, Documents,...

Comment: Ok. Two questions is there a way to get the default Path for say, Documents? And question two hwo can I find out the android version so that I know where I need to create the file or look for it? Because I need it to keep it compatible with previous versions that already had the file in that location

Comment: File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "this_is_a_test");

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.